# django score not work when i move aplication to another project

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

hi everybody i move app in another project for quiz he is work but showin the score is not work thats the template

```
 <div class="total" style="display:none">
<h2>  {{total}}congratilation you win your scoe is  </h2>
```

and thats a models.py

```
from django_auto_one_to_one import AutoOneToOneModel
class UserScores(AutoOneToOneModel(User,  related_name='user_id')):
score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
 
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.score)
```

and this views.py

```
class GameplayView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'gameApp/gameplay.html'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context  = super().get_context_data( **kwargs)
    self.request.session['q_count'] = 0
    self.request.session['winner'] =False
    self.request.session['score'] = 0
    self.request.session['right_answer'] = ""
```

Comment: Can you specify more the issue? I guess that view can not find template, if so we should see content of TEMPLATES variable from settings.py and path to the template from project level folder.

Comment: that is a url  path('gameplay', views.GameplayView.as_view(), name='gameplay'), and it is work with questions but result in the same templete not show and score filed in database is empty

Comment: that is a template   
<!-- manin scirpt which are checking response after ajax request to decide
does it goes to show next question or answer was false and redirect to index page
then giving you right answers and also checks if question finished again
redirect to index page but with congratulations -->
<script>

Comment: and this is the rest var q_count = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.question').first().css("display", "block");
});
  $("button").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).attr('id')
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{% url 'gameApp:check_answer' %}",
    data: {answer_id: btn},

Comment: and this is the finel rest   success: function(data){
      if (data=="ok") {
        console.log(btn)
          q_count++;
          $("button[id="+btn+"]").removeClass("btn-

Comment: primary").addClass("btn-success");
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('.question:visible').next().css("display", "block");

Comment: $('.question:visible').prev().css("display", "none");
          }, 700);
          if (q_count==6) {
            $(location).attr("href", "{% url 'index' %}");
          }
addClass("btn-danger");